# from clause in mysql case

Tags: php, mysql, case

hello what i want is that to use from cluse in mysql case like below

i have three tables tab1,tab2 and tab3
tab 1 stores all the fields 
tab 2 store data if the value of eore is 1 
(eore is one field in tab 1 its value can be only 1 or 2 )
if the value is 2 then its data is stored in tab 3

what i want is that to fetch all the data of tab 1 with related data in table 2 or 3

the query is simething like

```
select data1,dat2 case eore when '1' 
then select data14,data54,data56 from tab2 
when '2' then select data22,data34,data66 
from table3 end from table1 order by id desc limit 50
```

what i tried is like

```
 SELECT m.verify,m.mid,
CASE eore
WHEN '1' THEN c.mobile
     WHEN '2' THEN d.gender
  ELSE NULL END AS 'expose'
  FROM epmem m 
    INNER JOIN empl c ON c.rid = m.mid
   INNER JOIN comp d ON d.rid = m.mid
  ORDER BY m.mid DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

it shows no results .........

Comment: If there are no results, then nothing matches the joins.

Comment: it matches ..........

Comment: Please use punctuation in your description. That would make it a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use case like that, you can only have a single from caluse in each query. Left join tab2 and tab3 on tab1, and use if() function or case structure to decide which fields to show.

```
select tab1.*,
       if(eore=1,tab2.field1,tab3.field1) as field1,
       if(eore=1,tab2.field2,tab3.field2) as field2,
       ... 
from left join tab2 on tab1.id=tab2.id left join tab3 on tab1.id=tab3.id
```

I used hypothetical fields to join the tables, you need to use your own join criteria.